# How to close window in apex builder on clicking a button

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an apex page where I have a button "SAVE & CLOSE" . On click of that button, I first want to save the data and then close the page.

I have a PLSQL code at point "Processing" to save the data.

I have then created a Branch at Point = "After Processing" and Type ="PLSQL Procedure" and written below code to close the window.

```
Begin
htp.p('<script type="text/javascript" >');
htp.p('window.close();');
htp.p('</script>');
end;
```

I have added the button's name in server side condition : When button Pressed.

But this doesn't work. When I click on apply, it doesn't close the window. It gives me an error :

```
 "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 "
```

Can you please help me resolve this error and tell how can I close the window in button click.

Thanks,

Abha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I got it working with other method :

Instead of type  : PLSQL Procedure" select Type = "Page or URL Redirect"
and give 
       javascript:window.close() 
in the Target.

This works.

Comment: The problem for me with javascript:window.close() is that it closes the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only APEX components and not write a single line of code :)

Set action for your button to "Submit page" - so all items will be submitted to use their values in processing. Image below will help you.

Now, for processing your pl/sql code use process in processing(left side on the picture).

Here you can create a new process and set type to "**Close dialog**" this process will automatically close the window. Without any javascript etc.. Apex is processing from top to bottom, so if you make this process last, it will always close the window after all processes are done. 
You can as well set process server side condition, so it will not trigger every time.

[image: settings of button action]

Be careful with javascript - some web browsers are processing them in different way.

Hope it will help. Have a nice day !

Comment: Thanks a lot...That worked too :). I agree it is better to avoid javascript if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was make the page Modal. Then I added a Button called btnClosePage with a Dynamic Action (True Event) that calls "Close Dialog". I am working in Oracle Apex 20.2.